# Android gridview with 4 columns

Tags: android, gridview

I have to make a UI that is like .NET gridview, 4 columns.

1. product_name (TextView)
2. product_quantity (Spinner)
3. price (Textview)
4. delete button (Button, to delete the row)

So, my question is , what is the best way/control of Android sdk, to do the above UI. As I am new at Android, so I think Gridview is good.

Already followed the http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/ but when I try to use 4 columns with spinner, then only shows text. how I can show the little spinner in the gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView is best for your case as your data is repetitive and contains multiple attributes that is difficult to view in a gridview.  See this tutorial : http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will go with Listview.